# Relationship in cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to make the relationship between the tables
I read The documentations in cakephp3, and tons of post in stackoverflow, and still can’t get any result. I have two tables.

- `category (id, name, published, created, modified)`
- `portfolio (id, category_id, name, created, modified)`

I want to display every element of portofolio with category like this:

```
Category Cars

* element 1: Bmw
* element 2: Audi
* element 3: Ford
```

How can i make this relation and display?

In categories model I write :

```
 $this->belongsTo('Portfolios', [
              'foreignKey' => 'id'
          ]);
```

And this is the query:

```
$portfolios_category = $this->Categories->find()
            ->contain(['Portfolios'])
            ->where(['Categories.published' => 1])
            ->order(['Categories.created' => 'desc'])
            ->all();
```

Comment: The `foreignKey` in your `belongsTo` declaration should be `category_id`, not `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Just one correction :

```
 $this->belongsTo('Portfolios', [
              'foreignKey' => 'category_id'
 ]);
```

After that loop through `$portfolios_category` ,
hope you will get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Start using the command prompt.
Go to your project_folder/bin/ and open command prompt.

Then type

```
cake bake model
```

then you will get the list of Table with model name,
then type

```
cake bake model <ModelName>
```

ex:

```
cake bake model Category
```

```
cake bake model Portfolio
```